# Failed to install sumo binaries on macOS

Tags: sumo, flow-project

I have some trouble installing the sumo binaries. See the logs:

```
Installing sumo binaries
~/sumo_binaries/bin ~/flow
--2019-06-27 15:58:18--  https://akreidieh.s3.amazonaws.com/sumo/flow-0.3.1/binaries-mac.tar.xz
正在解析主机 akreidieh.s3.amazonaws.com (akreidieh.s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.219.116.98
正在连接 akreidieh.s3.amazonaws.com (akreidieh.s3.amazonaws.com)|52.219.116.98|:443... 已连接。
已发出 HTTP 请求，正在等待回应... 404 Not Found
2019-06-27 15:58:20 错误 404：Not Found。
```

Answer (score 2):

As of July 1st 2019, the issue has been resolved and you'll find the file at the said address.

---

Original answer:

At the moment (June 2019), Flow is in the process of moving to a newer version. That is why the file https://akreidieh.s3.amazonaws.com/sumo/flow-0.3.1/binaries-mac.tar.xz is not found.

If you want the fix this for now and have a working file, you can open the script you are running and modify the address of the file:

Change

```
https://akreidieh.s3.amazonaws.com/sumo/flow-0.3.1/binaries-mac.tar.xz
```

to

```
https://akreidieh.s3.amazonaws.com/sumo/flow-0.3.0/binaries-mac.tar.xz
```

Comment: We just upoaded the file that was not there previously!

Comment: You can now even download `https://akreidieh.s3.amazonaws.com/sumo/flow-0.3.1/binaries-mac.tar.xz`